# numpy.array_equal returns False for matching np arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, matrix-inverse

I'm having trouble getting the correct output from numpy.array_equal. The identity array is created using np.eye(size), and the `result_ab` array I'm comparing it with was built with np.array([]).

I keep getting the opposite result from what I expect. I've tested with both integer and float arrays and keep getting False when it should return True.

I've tested with allclose and array_equiv, but I don't think those are the right methods for this (they also tend to fail or give false positives). I've also printed the type of the `result_ab` and `identity` arrays and it returned `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` for both.

I am getting an empty array for the `identity` output.

````
rows = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
cols = int(input("Enter the number of columns: "))

#create placeholder for rows and cols lists
row_list = []
col_list = []

matrix_a = []
matrix_b = []

res_ab = np.array([])

#check if matrices have same number of rows, cols
def check(rows, cols):
  if rows != cols:
    print("The matrix must be square. Enter the same number of rows and columns.")
  else:
    m_a_input(rows)
    m_b_input(rows)

#create for loop to get 1 digit per row index
def m_a_input(rows):
  for i in range(rows):
    row = list(map(int, input("Enter row digits separated by a space").split()))
    matrix_a.append(row)
  print(matrix_a)

def m_b_input(rows):
  for i in range(rows):
    row = list(map(int, input("Enter row digits separated by a space").split()))
    matrix_b.append(row)
  print(matrix_b)

def mul_matrices(matrix_a, matrix_b):
  res_ab = np.matmul(matrix_a, matrix_b)
  print(res_ab)

def is_identity(res_ab):
    # Get the size of the matrix
    size = res_ab.shape[0]
    # Create the identity matrix of the same size
    identity = np.identity(size)
    print(identity)
    print(res_ab)
    # Check if the matrix is equal to the identity matrix using numpy.allclose
    if np.array_equal(res_ab, identity) == True:
      print("true")
    else:
      print("false")

check(rows, cols)
mul_matrices(matrix_a, matrix_b)
is_identity(res_ab)```
````

Comment: what's the `dtypes`?

Comment: Both `dtypes` are returning as `float64`.

Comment: your code seems to work correctly, when I run it on my end?

Comment: your function doesnt seem to be using rows parameter, please make sure you are not missing an important part of code to include here?

Comment: Be careful when comparing flosts.  allclose may be better.  Sometimes you need to actually look at the values, or do a elementwise `==` or difference.  `array_equal` can fail in a number different ways.  We call this 'debugging'

Comment: Thank you, @CemKoçak - I did remove the rows parameter as it was not needed. I've posted with the complete script. I believe what's happening is that I'm having issues getting the correct res_ab value in the `is_identity` function, as it seems to be using the empty list from when I initialized the variable.

Comment: I see lots of `print` statements in your code, but I don't those results or much discussion of them.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, thanks for your advice! I did change my final code to `allclose`. The print statements were my way of checking the values as I went.

Comment: Looks like you're unclear on the concept of variable scope - `res_ab = np.matmul(matrix_a, matrix_b)` is assigning to a local variable. You also really need to get familiar with using return values instead of having your functions try to store data to global variables directly.

Comment: Sometimes the print results help us diagnose your problem.  If your code is complete we can run it ourselves, and track what is going on.  But I also read the question from my phone or tablet, and can't actually run anything (except in my head)

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer in the dedicated space below. Do not edit the question to add an "update"